# how to remove without https versions of my site from google search?

Tags: http, https, blogger

I have created a site on blogger with custom domain. I have added the site to google search but after a day i migrated http to https using 301 redirect and chrome showing green signal of secure.. then i added also the https version of my site to google search console.now google crawl my site somewhere with http and somewhere without http.. i want to replace all the without http searches to https searches. how can i do this?? please solve this.. my site name is Hunt Hob and Address is https://www.hunthob.org

Comment: Try to use 'Google webmaster' and maybe this particular page:   https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812/?hl=en

Comment: but for which site? because I have four sites in my google webmaster

Comment: {https , without https, www, without www